# How can I uninstall Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

OK, so I know that other people asked exactly the same... but I just moved from Nouveau to Nvidia using [this tutorial](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-remove-nouveau-drivers-ubuntu), and the new drivers are really, really, really slow. How can I remove Nvidia drivers and recover the open ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you added things to the blacklist, **remove them now from the list** with `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
2. Now close your session and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> in the login menu.
3. Login with your username and password.
4. Run `sudo stop lightdm`, which will stop X11 (including the standard login menu!)
5. Now exec `sudo nvidia-uninstall`
6. Press **Yes** to restore from a backup.
7. You may find errors related with non-empty folders. Ignore them.
8. If you removed Nouveau, run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
9. Now you can finish with `sudo reboot`

Comment: The question is about restoring the open graphics drivers (Nouveau), not about installing ``nvidia-current``. Additionally, ``sudo stop lightdm`` won't work. I think you mean ``sudo service lightdm stop``.

Comment: 1) Isn't `nvidia-current` the same as Noveau?

Comment: 2) This is my question AND my answer, so I tested myself the instructions :P

Comment: Nouveau is provided by ``xserver-xorg-video-nouveau``. ``nvidia-current`` will blacklist ``nouveau`` in ``/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf``.

Comment: And please, use negative votes as few as possible. Comment or flag instead.

Comment: From @gfournier: sudo apt-get purge nvidia* and installing xserver-xorg-video-nouveau broke my configuration and I couldn't fix it (although I don't try much). I'll try Bublebee

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Solved like this:

1. Boot as normal and get to login screen
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
3. Login with your username and password.
4. type `sudo stop lightdm` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, stops X11
5. type `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - clears all nvidia items
6. type `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - will install this package or tell you if it is already there.
7. type `sudo reboot`

This got me back up and running (although no icons in Unity Launcher - since need correct graphic drivers) check **system settings** to search for **Additional drivers** to see if this can be addressed - although adding wrong drivers may cause the system to be faulty or freeze after login.