# Why doesn't ubuntu show the latest Nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Apparently the Nvidia 319 drivers have been out for a while now, but the latest you can download in ubuntu is 313? I NEED the latest drivers, but I've read over and over again that if I install them manually via the nvidia website that I'll run into issues when ubuntu updates drop.

What do I do? I have an Nvidia 670 and I'm getting crappy performance with the 313 drivers.

Comment: What issues, and why, and what do you mean by "ubuntu updates drop"? If you need the 319 driver, install it.

Comment: took your advice, installed the 319 driver. It wrecked my ubuntu install. PC only booted to a blinking cursor. i got into recover console and removed drivers, now i'm finally back in but Unity is gone forever. there is no way to bring unity back, i've tried it all. now i'm stuck with gnome. I loved unity. i'm tired of having to reformat everytime something doesn't jive right with ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry for your troubles. Things don't always work as expected, and software isn't perfect.

Most of the packages in the Ubuntu repositories [are somewhat outdated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software). Like it or not, this is the way it has been since the beginning. The next version of Ubutnu, due in October, should have the 319 driver in the repositories, tested and ready to use.

You can [remove the manually installed Nvidia driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/189348/20054) if it causes problems. No need to reformat anything.

Comment: I would agree with Mike.  Don't reformat/reinstall the OS every time something blows up.  It's really just a matter of 'backing out,' cleaning up the mess, and then reinstalling what you know worked before.  Unity should be able to be recovered still.. especially if a single driver upgrade was the only reason it's failing to function now.