# Installed the latest nvidia drivers and ubuntu won't start anymore :(

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I had a fresh install of 13.10. The graphics were laggy and it was crashing when I was changing wallpapers so I went ahead to install the latest Nnvidia drivers. (it was using some generic one before that).

I followed a tutorial that had me add a PPA rep and install it from there. All went good but, when I restarted; Ubuntu doesn't load but gives me a blank black screen after I select it from the boot menu.

P.S.

Here is the [tutorial](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-the-Latest-NVIDIA-331-20-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-10-399182.shtml) I followed.

Comment: Have you try rebooting into recovery mode first?  Look into there and see if you can change back to the previous driver.  Also, remove that PPA while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the driver: [How can I uninstall Nvidia proprietary drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189347/how-can-i-uninstall-nvidia-proprietary-drivers/) - and then install the one from the repos (you can use the "Software & Updates" app).

"All went good but when I restarted" = all went good until I tried to use the driver.

You shouldn't be surprised, even the tutorial you mentioned says "they don’t risk uploading a piece of software that has yet to be proven stable". If a driver is available in the repos - it means it is generally safe to use. If a driver is made available by the vendor - it could mean **anything**: from "tried & tested" to "go & try & mess up your system as you like".

Comment: Thank you! It's odd but after few restarts it booted up just fine and even shows that it uses the nvidia driver in "About this computer"
And everything works snappy now.
What could be the reason for that?

Comment: No idea. Needs logs and someone more clever than me.